# How to set caption font to \uppercase?

Tags: fonts, captions, capitalization

I want to set the caption font for all tables in the document (so I want to do it in the preamble, and not have to specify it in each table) to use uppercase letter (not sc, the small case already provided by the caption package). I have tried declaring the caption font with "\uppercase", "\MakeUppercase", "\MakeTextUppercase" but to no success (also all combinations with {} at the end as shown in preamble below). Any suggestions?

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[]{caption}
\def\tablename{TABLE}
\DeclareCaptionFont{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{}}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    font=up,
}

\begin{document}
```

Many thanks :)

Comment: Don't do this. On the technical side it is fragile and difficult to uppercase  longer text with unknown content, on the typografical side it will look horrible. Should your caption shout at people?

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I am following a style guide which wants it this way.... Luckily the table titles aren't very long :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either use `\DeclareCaptionFormat` or `\DeclareCaptionTextFormat` for that purpose, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{up}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\captionsetup[table]{
    labelsep=period,
    justification=centering,
    textformat=up,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Hello World!}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

BTW: I second Ulrikes "Don't do this".

Comment: I have a problem while capitizing the table caption. I have subscript in my cation text, which I want it to remain small letter.  But, with the above solution, even the subscript got capitized, Eg. TABLE 1 : COMPARISON WHEN N_b=5. I want b to remain as small letter. Please help.

Comment: I need to have not the caption itself in uppercase, but also "TABLE 1" instead of "Table 1". I experimented with "format" instead of "textformat" in your above code, but to no avail. How can this be done?